# How to Destroy Ads Every X Minute in Java?

Tags: java

i need help for destroy ads every X minute (like 2 minute) after ads showing close button, i already implemented ads (Unity Ads) to showing every 5 second after i click the button. Here is my example code :
`code`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main_1 );
    String unity_id = Variable.getString( MainActivity.UNITY_ID, this, getString( R.string.unity_ads ) );
    UnityAds.addListener(MainActivity1.this);
    UnityAds.initialize( this, unity_id );
}
public void onClick(View view) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            Log.d("Ads", "Ads will be show in 5 secs");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    String placementId = "video";
                    if (UnityAds.isReady( placementId )) {
                        UnityAds.show( MainActivity1.this, placementId );
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG"," Interstitial not loaded");
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

`code`

Can anyone help me what function i need to use to automatically destroy the ads every X minute after close button ads appear?

Thank you for your help.